# VBA: Interrupt double click (two single clicks)

Tags: vba, excel, double-click

**Scenario**

I have an excel worksheet where I am using a certain cell (say `C3`) as a button functionality: Whenever the cell is selected (SelectionChange), a certain function is executed.

In order to be able to click the cell several times in a row, after performing the desired functionality I am setting the selection back to a neutral cell (say `A1`). This way, `C3` can be selected again and the function can run again.

**Problem**

I would like to click the button cell (`C3`) several times in a row in quick succession. However, when I click it twice shortly in a row (double-click), it actually enters into edit mode for the neutral cell (`A1`).

I am aware of the option `Cancel = True` in the BeforeDoubleClick event handler. However, this doesn't work for me because it cancels the entire event altogether: With `Cancel = True` the second click will simply be cancelled altogether and my desired function simply won't run.

**Question**

Any smart ideas on how to prevent the double click while at the same time still interpreting the second click as just a normal single click?

Comment: As there is no click event I assume you use the SelectionChange event for your code, right. Maybe it's a good idea to show the code otherwise you probably will not get much help.

Comment: You can easily resolve you problem if you disable  `Allow editing directly in cells` on `File > Options > Advanced > Editing Options`.

Comment: @Pspl please stop answering questions in comments. If you think you have an answer, post an answer. Or don't post at all. Comments should not be used for posting answers.

Comment: @teylyn, you're completely right. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an actual button? Your double-click problem would just vanish then.

Comment: @teylyn I don't know where you got the idea that suggested solutions can't be proposed in a Comment. It's done all the time, especially for things that may not be what the OP is looking for. If the OP later responds positively the Comment can always be expanded on as an Answer.

Comment: @Pspl What you did is just fine... If the OP responds and tells you this approach is OK you can always expand on it and post it as an Answer. Since it is, of course, a non-programming approach, it's certainly better first in Comments.

Comment: @Cindy Meister, thank you for your support. Actually I see this kind of suggestion on comment sections everywhere (like you said). But I surely don't want to start any kind of conflict of ideas...

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: That's definitely a possible solution. However, my project is significantly more complex than I described and I don't want to have separate buttons for the many functions I am executing this way.

Comment: @Storax: My bad, I'm using the SelectionChange event, not click.
Showing code won't add anything to the discussion, however, because 1) it's way more complex than I described, I just boiled it down to the acutal problem and 2) this is a general principle and I'm interested in a general solution to prevent a double-click as described.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding my comment to an answer:

Can you disable `Allow editing directly in cells` on `File > Options > Advanced > Editing Options`? Although this is a non-programming approach, it may be the simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: Good input, however, I still want to allow editing directly in cells

Answer (score 1):

You could try cell security.   Do not allow locked cells to be selected and use VBA to turn security on or off.

The cell could be unlocked by default and a transparent label could lock the cell on mouse rollover.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't work either because I need to be able to select a cell in order to unselect the button cell.

Comment: What happens when you just put a label over the cell and the onclick even for the label simply selects the cell underneath ?  i do not experience any double clicking delay on the label... but i dont know what the impact is to your button-like cell

Comment: I don't think that would help my problem. Basically I want to get two single clicks even when I click twice in short succession. I think the problem is that VBA only offers a BeforeDoubleClick event and no AfterDoubleClick

Comment: don't use the double click event!  use the single click. i through it together and tried it out with my last response. the thing is, i don't know what you're doing with that cell so i can't take it to the next step.  but i'm telling you i have confirmed i can click a label as my bony fingers can click and that cell is getting selected every time. this is how i confirmed it: i created the label and set onclick to select a specific cell. i had a worksheet selectionchange event that pulled the selection off that cell.  the speed of those selection changes were so fast i couldn't verify visually.

Comment: so i added a flag and sent its value to a cell.   > click < [select target cell] (flag = not flag) [sheet change pulls away from target cell]  and when i went   >click< >click< >click< >click< >click< >click< >click<  that little true false was flipping like a license plate in a tornado   no delay.  again, this is onevent click - not double click

Comment: Oh, I understand now. It's definitely a good workaround, but I'd prefer not having to add a label (because I have many cells like it).